# About “Unexpected 503 response from chrome-error”

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-server-side

I wanted to add RadzenPanelMenuItem in my MainLayout.When I added an item
with a Path, I got this error. After that I can not reach in my chrome or other other browsers. Is there someone help me to resolve this?

> "Could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/:
> Unexpected 503 response from
> chrome-error://chromewebdata/neterror.rollup.js.map: Unsupported
> protocol "chrome-error:"

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<RadzenLayout>
    <RadzenHeader>
        <RadzenStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" AlignItems="AlignItems.Center" Gap="0">
            <RadzenSidebarToggle Click="@(() => _sidebarExpanded = !_sidebarExpanded)" />
            <img src="assets/images/favicon.png" alt="Favicon" style="height: 32px; width: 32px; margin-right: 5px;" />
            <RadzenLabel Text="TEST" />
        </RadzenStack>
    </RadzenHeader>
    <RadzenSidebar @bind-Expanded="@_sidebarExpanded">
        <RadzenPanelMenu Style="width:300px">
            <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="General" Icon="home">
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Buttons" Path="buttons" Icon="account_circle"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Menu" Path="menu" Icon="line_weight"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="FileInput" Path="fileinput" Icon="attach_file"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Dialog" Path="dialog" Icon="perm_media"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Notification" Path="notification" Icon="announcement"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
            </RadzenPanelMenuItem>
            <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Inputs" Icon="payment">
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="CheckBox" Path="checkbox" Icon="check_circle"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="TextBox" Path="textbox" Icon="input"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="TextArea" Path="textarea" Icon="description"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Password" Path="password" Icon="payment"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Numeric" Path="numeric" Icon="aspect_ratio"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="DatePicker" Path="datepicker" Icon="date_range"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
            </RadzenPanelMenuItem>
            <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Data" Icon="save">
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="DataGrid" Path="datagrid" Icon="grid_on"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="DataList" Path="datalist" Icon="list"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="DropDown" Path="dropdown" Icon="dns"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="DropDownDataGrid" Path="dropdown-datagrid" Icon="receipt"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="ListBox" Path="listbox" Icon="view_list"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="TemplateForm" Path="templateform" Icon="line_style"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
            </RadzenPanelMenuItem>
            <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Containers" Icon="account_box">
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Tabs" Path="tabs" Icon="tab"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Panel" Path="panel" Icon="content_paste"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Fieldset" Path="fieldset" Icon="account_balance_wallet"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="Card" Path="card" Icon="line_style"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
            </RadzenPanelMenuItem>
            <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="More">
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem  Text="Item1"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem  Text="Item2"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="More items">
                    <RadzenPanelMenuItem Text="More sub items">
                        <RadzenPanelMenuItem  Text="Item3"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                        <RadzenPanelMenuItem  Text="Item4"></RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                    </RadzenPanelMenuItem>
                </RadzenPanelMenuItem>
            </RadzenPanelMenuItem>
        </RadzenPanelMenu>
        <div class="rz-p-4">
            Sidebar
        </div>
    </RadzenSidebar>

    <RadzenBody>
        <div class="rz-p-4">
            Body
        </div>
    </RadzenBody>
</RadzenLayout>



@code {
    bool _sidebarExpanded = true;

}
```

I just add a path. I did not anything else. But VS debug failed suddenly. I have tried two different projects.

Comment: I have found solution. I just added @page "/" to MainLayout.razor  :)